# how to prove that turning a set into a sequence and back is an identity in dafny

Tags: dafny

Hi Relatively new to Dafny and have defined methods set2Seq and seq2Set for conversion between sets and seqs. But can only find how to write a function fseq2Set from sets to sequences.
I can not find how to define fseq2Set.  As Lemmas can not reference methods this makes proving the identity beyond me.  Any help much appreciated?

Code:

```
function method fseq2Set(se: seq<int>) :set<int>
    { set x:int | x in se :: x }
method seq2Set(se: seq<int>) returns (s:set<int>) 
    { s := set x:int | x in se :: x; }
method  set2Seq(s: set<int>)  returns (se:seq<int>)
  requires s != {}
  ensures s == fseq2Set(se)
  decreases |s|
{
    var y :| y in s;
    var tmp ;
    if (s=={y}) {tmp := [];} else {tmp := set2Seq(s-{y});}
    se := [y] + tmp;
    assert (s-{y}) + {y} == fseq2Set([y] + tmp);
}  
/* below fails */
function fset2Seq(s:set<int>):seq<int> 
decreases s { var y :| y in s ; [y] + fset2Seq(s-{y})    }
lemma cycle(s:set<int>) ensures forall s:set<int> ::  fseq2Set(fset2Seq(s)) == s {   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there is kind of a lot going on here. First of all, I'm not sure if you intended to do anything with the methods `seq2Set` and `set2Seq`, but they don't seem to be relevant to your failure, so I'm just going to ignore them and focus on the functions.

Speaking of functions, Danfy reports an error on your definition of `fset2Seq`, because `s` might be empty. In that case, we should return the empty sequence, so I adjusted your definition to:

```
function fset2Seq(s:set<int>):seq<int> 
  decreases s
{
  if s == {} then []
  else 
    var y := Pick(s);
    [y] + fset2Seq(s - {y})
}

function Pick(s: set<int>): int
  requires s != {}
{
  var x :| x in s; x
}
```

which fixes that error. Notice that I also wrapped the let-such-that operator `:|` in a function called `Pick`. This is essential, but hard to explain. Just trust me for now.

Now on to the lemma. Your lemma is stated a bit weirdly, because it takes a parameter `s`, but then the `ensures` clause doesn't mention `s`. (Instead it mentions a completely different variable, also called `s`, that is bound by the `forall` quantifier!) So I adjusted it to get rid of the quantifier, as follows:

```
lemma cycle(s:set<int>)
  ensures fseq2Set(fset2Seq(s)) == s
```

Next, I follow My Favorite Heuristic™ in program verification, which is that *the structure of the proof follows the structure of the program*. In this case, the "program" in question is `fseq2Set(fset2Seq(s))`. Starting from our input `s`, it first gets processed recursively by `fset2Seq` and then through the set comprehension in `fseq2Set`. So, I expect a proof by induction on `s` that follows the structure of `fset2Seq`. That structure is to branch on whether `s` is empty, so let's do that in the lemma too:

```
lemma cycle(s:set<int>)
  ensures fseq2Set(fset2Seq(s)) == s
{
  if s == {} {
  } else {
  }
...
```

Dafny reports an error on the else branch but not on the if branch. In other words, Dafny has proved the base case, but it needs help with the inductive case. The next thing that `fset2Seq(s)` does is call `Pick(s)`. Let's do that too.

```
lemma cycle(s:set<int>)
  ensures fseq2Set(fset2Seq(s)) == s
{
  if s == {} {
  } else {
    var y := Pick(s);
...
```

Now we know from its definition that `fset2Seq(s)` is going to return `[y] + fset2Seq(s - {y})`, so we can copy-paste our `ensures` clause and manually substitute this expression.

```
lemma cycle(s:set<int>)
  ensures fseq2Set(fset2Seq(s)) == s
{
  if s == {} {
  } else {
    var y := Pick(s);
    assert fseq2Set([y] + fset2Seq(s - {y})) == s;
...
```

Dafny reports an error on this assertion, which is not surprising, since it's just a lightly edited version of the `ensures` clause we're trying to prove. But importantly, Dafny *no longer* reports an error on the `ensures` clause itself. In other words, if we can prove this assertion, we are done.

Looking at this assert, we can see that `fseq2Set` is applied to two lists appended together. And we would expect that to be equivalent to separately converting the two lists to sets, and then taking their union. We could prove a lemma to that effect, or we could just ask Dafny if it already knows this fact, like this:

```
lemma cycle(s:set<int>)
  ensures fseq2Set(fset2Seq(s)) == s
{
  if s == {} {
  } else {
    var y := Pick(s);
    assert fseq2Set([y] + fset2Seq(s - {y})) == fseq2Set([y]) + fseq2Set(fset2Seq(s - {y}));
    assert fseq2Set([y] + fset2Seq(s - {y})) == s;
...
```

(Note that the newly added assertion is *before* the last one.)

Dafny now accepts our lemma. We can clean up a little by deleting the the base case and the final assertion that was just a copy-pasted version of our ensures clause. Here is the polished proof.

```
lemma cycle(s:set<int>)
  ensures fseq2Set(fset2Seq(s)) == s
{
  if s != {} {
    var y := Pick(s);
    assert fseq2Set([y] + fset2Seq(s - {y})) == fseq2Set([y]) + fseq2Set(fset2Seq(s - {y}));
  }
}
```

I hope this explains how to prove the lemma and also gives you a little bit of an idea about how to make progress when you are stuck.

I did not explain `Pick`. Basically, as a rule of thumb, you should just always wrap `:|` in a function whenever you use it. To understand why, see the [Dafny power user](http://leino.science/dafny-power-user/) posts on [iterating over collecion](http://leino.science/papers/krml275.html) and [functions over set elements](http://leino.science/papers/krml274.html). Also, see Rustan's paper [Compiling Hilbert's epsilon operator](https://easychair.org/publications/paper/dM).